# Telnet server example

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

Today I installed NodeMCU on one ESP8266 module.

I made a simple telnet server (logging in to the AP is already done and connected)

```
srv=net.createServer(net.TCP,7200)
srv:listen(23,function(conn)

    conn:on("receive", function(conn,telnetdata)
        print(telnetdata)

        conn:send("Got it\r\n")
    end)

    conn:on("sent",function(conn)

        print("[Sent]");
        --conn:close();
        --collectgarbage();
    end)

end)
```

I can telnet into the ESP8266 using Putty and I can send static data back to Putty (`conn:send("Got it\r\n")`).

What I want to do is to send data to Putty from the esp serial port (UART). I've googled for an example without success. BTW I'm using ESPlorer to program the ESP and to send data back to putty.

Instead of using `conn:send("Got it\r\n")` I want to dynamically type the response. I've tried `uart:on` callback but I haven't fully understood how it works.

Answer (score 2):

NodeMCU has an "official" [Telnet example in the repository](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/tree/release/lua_modules/telnet). However, that one is also WiFi/socket-based.

If you're connected to the device through ESPlorer (i.e. serial/UART) you can't open another serial connection. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36779799/131929 for details.

Comment: I understand about using the same serial connection as esplorer, how about using an arduino to receive and send trough the serial port? Basically I need a simple bridge between arduino and putty (telnet)

Answer (score 0):

Marcel thank you for your answer.

The link posted is not exactly what I need but it offered good info.

I finally came up with this code that works as a simple bridge between putty and a micro controller (arduino mega 2560 in this case)

```
socket = net.createServer(net.TCP,7200)
socket:listen(23,function(c)

    c:on("receive",function(c,l)
        uart.write(0, l)
    end)

    c:on("disconnection",function(c)
        -- not yet implemented
    end)

    uart.on("data", 0,
        function(data)
            c:send(data)
    end, 0)
end)
```